# Plugins prioritization

Tags: magento2, plugin, sort, after-plugin

The [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=quick_search&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=prior#prioritizing-plugins) mentions the sort order is always from lowest to highest, except when around plugins are used, then

> The around plugin’s method affects the flow of all plugins that are executed after it.

Affects them how? If you have multiple plugins and **all** of them include around plugins, the order of execution **is** in fact from **highest to lowest** for the after plugins. I did an example similar to the ones in the documentation, with a **callable** included:

|  | PLUGIN1 | PLUGIN2 | PLUGIN3 | PLUGIN4 | PLUGIN5 | PLUGIN6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sortOrder | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 |
| before | beforeDispatch() | beforeDispatch() | beforeDispatch() | beforeDispatch() | beforeDispatch() | beforeDispatch() |
| around |  | aroundDispatch() |  |  | aroundDispatch() | aroundDispatch() |
| after | afterDispatch() | afterDispatch() | afterDispatch() | afterDispatch() | afterDispatch() | afterDispatch() |

Where the execution is: before 122345566 => callback => after 665345212. I'm curious about the 665345 part. It seems that after plugins are executed from **highest to lowest** if there is also an around plugin, otherwise lowest to highest. Could you explain this behaviour?